# Nested If dilemma

Tags: c++

I am having troubles understanding this issue. The code is really basic but it behaves rather unexpectedly. The code is the simplified version of a routine to extract and save to a separate file the data for the day 15 of each month out of a daily database. Where is the problem ? The first cout prints the number of any day the outer if is entered. Then there are some conditional lines to select the right day ( not really important in this example ) and then there is the block, the inner if, that should print the data for the day 15 to the new file. Now, as you can see, while the outer loop ( attention ! ) is entered only on the 10th ( and this is already wrong - it should have written all the numbers from 11 to 15 ) but then it also prints that the file is written on the 15 ! Where is the problem ? The OUTER IF was entered only on the 10th, how can be the INNER IF be execute on the 15th ????

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    string newdata="mamma";
    string risultato="-";
    string PriorLine="-";
    int PriorDay=0;
    int lastmonth=0;

        // Loops through all the months
        for (int mese=1; mese <=12; mese++)
        { 
            //Loops through all the days in the month
            for(int day=1; day<=30; day++)
            {
                // at the month's beginning these 2 strings are set ="-"
                if (mese != lastmonth)
                {
                 risultato="-";
                 PriorLine="-";
                 }
                // if we are between the 10th and the 20th and the result is still to be found
                if (day>=10 && day<=20 && risultato=="-")
                {   
                       cout << day << endl;  // LISTS ALL THE DAYS THIS LOOP IS ENTERED
                       if (day=15)  // if it is exactly day 15 print that day's result
                              risultato=newdata;    
                       // if that month in the data there is no day 15 and 
                       // this is the second pass, choose the closest !  
                       if (day>15 && PriorLine !="-")
                       {
                            if (abs(day-15)<=abs(15-PriorDay))
                                   risultato=newdata;
                            else
                                   risultato=PriorLine;
                        }
                        PriorLine=newdata;
                        PriorDay=day;
                        if (risultato != "-")
                        {   
                            // writes the result ( risultato ) in a file
                            cout << "file written on the " << day << endl;

                         }
                 }                  
                 lastmonth=mese;
           }
    }    
    system("pause");
    return 0;
```

}

Comment: Have you traced through this in a debugger?

Comment: i think this `if (day>=10 && day<=20 && risultato=="-")` can be inside `if (mese != lastmonth)` since the former fails if the latter fails.

Comment: `for(int day=1; day<=30; day++)` May have escaped you attention that May has 31 days in it?! - And May is just around the corner!

Comment: How many times can I put May into a sentence?!

Comment: @EdHeal I reduced my days of work !  :-) This is just an example to show the problem.

Answer (score 7):

`if (day=15)` assigns 15 to `day` and returns `true`. You need `if (day==15)`

Comment: If you adopt the thinking '15=day` this problem is avoided.

Comment: @Roger Rowland   Thanks ! Problem solved ! Ed, you look like you have a character rather similar to mine; in real life we would be great friends, I suppose !

Answer (score 1):

When I simply compiled your code with `g++ -Wall` I got a warning:

```
error: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value
```

On this line:

```
if (day=15)  // if it is exactly day 15 print that day's result
```

I'm willing to be the compiler has told you what your problem is.  I suggest you enable all warnings in your build system.

Comment: oh, come on ! I lost 4 for reputation for this ! It was a simple overlook ! The comparison == was written correctly somewhere else in the very code I posted above and it is something everybody knows ... how can people be so bad ???

Comment: I guess people don't like spending their time figuring out something that any reasonable compiler made in the last 10 years would tell you.  Your question's wording and formatting left something to be desired too.  But hey, don't worry about the few reputation points--if you keep at it, 4 points will be a rounding error!

Comment: btw, I have VisualStudio 2010, it did not give any warning. How to change its settings ?

Comment: The warning you needed here is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7hw7c1he(v=vs.80).aspx - so you need level 4 (the highest), which is explained here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/13b90fz7%28VS.71%29.aspx